# rm if there's a file with same basename

Tags: bash, rm, filename

Say I have the following files:

```
foo.coffee
foo.js
bar.js
```

Is there an easy way how to `rm *.js` if there's a corresponding `.coffee` file? In the example such a command would remove `foo.js` leaving:

```
foo.coffee
bar.js
```

I'm looking for some sort of a `rm` wrap as I need to do a recursive `rm -r`.

Comment: What do you mean by _recursive `rm -r`_ in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (using all the best practices!):

```
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.js; do
    coffee=${f%.js}.coffee
    [[ -f $coffee ]] && rm -v -- "$f"
done
```

- `nullglob` is a [shell optional behavior](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) so that `*.js` will expand to the empty string if there are no files with extension `js`.
- Use [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the extension `.js` and replace it with `.coffee` in the variable `coffee`.
- `rm` is used with the `-v` switch (verbose) so that you see what's happening.
- `rm` is also used with `--` that marks the end of options, just in case there's a file that starts with a hyphen: in that case, `rm` would be confused and try to interpret an option.
- The `[[ ... ]]` construct is a conditional construct and uses [conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). Notice I'm using the robust *double square bracket* `[[` and not the single `[`. Very good practice (in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)).
- Note that the quoting is perfect. It's all 100% safe regarding files that have spaces or funny symbols in their name.

For testing purposes, you should put `echo` in front of `rm`:

```
    [[ -f $coffee ]] && echo rm -v -- "$f"
```

so that it only echoes the command and doesn't remove anything. When you're happy with that, remove the `echo`.

Enjoy!

Comment: I wish I could give another +1 for spreading Bash best practices. About `[` vs `[[`, see also [BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29).

Answer (score 2):

Create this script (I called it remove.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$3" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory> <extension-to-remove> <conditional-extension>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "Invalid directory."
    exit 1
fi

for FILE in $(find $1 -name "*.$3"); do
    rm -v ${FILE%.$3}.$2
done
```

Then run `remove.sh <directory> js coffee`.